# Push is not a function in redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I writing a simple add to cart function using redux. When I try to add the product to array its throws an error:

> state.products.push is not a function.

**initial state**

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  products: []
};
```

I used redux-sauce to dispatch the action.

**reducer**

```
export const AddToCart = (state, { item }) => ({
  ...state,
  products: state.products.push(item),
});
```

Comment: Initialize state=INITIAL_STATE in reducer

Comment: initial state is same as reducer state

Comment: Change push to concat.  Push doesn’t return the array.

Comment: Do Not Mutate State https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state

Comment: Can you console log state in AddToCart and check whether products exist in state or not

Comment: initial is empty

Comment: tired with concat throws same error

Comment: I think this is an "all of the above" answer.  Don't mutate state, use `concat`, use `state = INITIAL_STATE`.  Does that work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are setting the value of `state.products` to the value returned by `push()`.  **The `push()` method does not return an array**.  It mutates the array, which you should not do in Redux, and [returns the new length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#return_value).  After you call this reducer you will have changed your `state.products` property from an array to a `number`.

You can use [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead.  This method returns a new array with the item appended to it.  It does not modify the original array so it's Redux-safe.

I'm not too familiar with redux-sauce, but it [seems like](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reduxsauce#complete-example) you need to include `state = INITIAL_STATE` on every case reducer.

```
export const AddToCart = (state = INITIAL_STATE, { item }) => ({
  ...state,
  products: state.products.concat(item),
});
```